# Level shifter problem

Tags: digital-logic, uart, level-shifting

I have a question regarding a level shifter schematic that I've implemented. I need to connect a 1v8 logic UART device to both an Arduino and a TTL232-3V3 cable. The Tx side works as expected and I can step down the 5 V logic from the Arduino to 2 V which is accepted by the 1v8 device. The 1v8 device gives a response which I can read just fine using the TTL cable. However I can not read it using the Arduino.

This is because for some reason the drain of the Rx level shifter is not pulled up to 5V when the bus is idle but rather stays at 2.2 V and I have no reason as to why it is doing this. It was working fine before when I was using a simple resistor divider to create the 2 V that is on the gate of the MOSFET. I changed this to a Zener diode configuration to create a more stable voltage. I already swapped the MOSFET once but the same thing happens

Why does the MOSFET do this, it seems like the Zener is damaging it somehow?? When LV side is high the Vgs voltage is 2 V - 1.8 V = 0.2 V which is lower than the minimal voltage required to switch the MOSFET (which is 0.8 V according to the datasheet), so this can't be it.

Ps. don't mind the BOOT button, it is designed to short the Rx line like this without damage. Also I tried disconnecting the Arduino Rx line and it's still 2.2 V (instead of 5 V) on the drain when the LV side is high

[image: UART configuration]

Comment: What is the voltage over the Zener?

Comment: The zener has a breakdown voltage of 2V and the 220 ohm resistor is small enough so that 2 volts is over the zener (2.012 to be exact)

Comment: RS232 to TTL(CMOS) ought to be inverted. Is that the application?

Comment: Maybe check if the LV TX pullup has current going to the LV TX when "idle". I get the impression during simulations that this could give the behaviour you described.